# Making buttons links

Tags: html

I am interested in making the hover-over buttons on my website clickable, but don't know how. My website is here: http://mathisbeauty.org/

The relevant code for the page itself looks like

> ```
> <div id="bar">
>     <div class="menuLink"><a href="index.html">Home</a></div>
>     <div class="menuLink"><a href="videos.html">Videos</a></div>
>     <div class="menuLink"><a href="articles.html">Articles</a></div>
>     <div class="menuLink"><a href="links.html">Links</a></div>
>     <div class="menuLink"><a href="aboutme.html">About me</a></div>
> </div>
> ```

and the CCS is (I believe!)

```
.menuLink
{
    height:36px;
    width: 120px;
    text-align:center;
    float:left;
    font-family:Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:14px;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#252F33;
    padding-top:19px;
}
menuLink:hover
{
background: url(bar2.png) repeat-x;
}
```

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: you mean you want your HOME button clickable? Right now i need to click onto the text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your links are clickable, the problem is that it is just the text that is currently a link. You just need to make the anchor the same size as the container they sit in `.menuLink`.

Add the following css and it should work..

```
.menuLink a {
    height: 36px;
    width: 120px;
    display: block;
}
```

**Edit**:

Use this instead, should give you the full box. To be honest I didn't notice the top half not being included.

```
.menuLink a {
    height: 57px;
    width: 120px;
    display: block;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    padding-top: 18px;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your code is right, but This is what you are looking for?

http://designshack.net/articles/css/four-simple-and-fun-css-button-hover-effects-for-beginners/

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you want to make the whole hovered area to be a link element.

You have to wrap the 
`<div class="menuLink">` element to `<a>` tag:

This also works:

```
<a class="menuLink" href="index.html"><span>Home</span></a>
```

Comment: Can you say more about what you mean when you write "You have to wrap the <div class="menuLink"> element to <a> tag:" ?

Comment: <a href="foo"><div class="menuLink"></div></a>

Answer (score 0):

```
 .menuLink a {display: block;padding: 21px 0; }
.menuLink {padding:0;}
```

This will set the width of the `a` to match the parent div `.menuLink`.

Comment: I tried this, and even though the whole cell is now clickable, now the hover over area is smaller than it used to be (it's only the top of the cell...). Any suggestions?